# how to do string replace (variable value) on one of lines appearing between two patterns and for multiple files

Tags: text-processing, search

File1.txt

```
ABC123DEF
START
A
B
C=??
D
END
UVZ789XYZ
START
A
B
C=??
D
END
```

Output expected is

```
ABC123DEF
START
A
B
C=123
D
END
UVZ789XYZ
START
A
B
C=789
D
END
```

How to do that using ´sed´ / ´awk´ / ´tcl´ / ´vim´?

Comment: vim has `:s///` and then `\1` , `\2` to re-use a partial match. `:h pattern` and `:h su`are the help commands. Vim has good general explanations, 90% applies to `sed` too. "Regex" is the keyword. (I just wanted to add a "r" to "sting" in the title, but it is pending...)

Comment: With the new layout my short intro above is a bit useless - that would be for one line, with limited complexity. Now `sed` would be perfect because of the "hold" funcionality (a real "stack", not just immediate \1, \2, ...). But: instead of programming in vim or sed, you might as well switch to awk, or perl, or anything. Do you have a reason for this: **"How to do that using ´sed´ / ´awk´ / ´tcl´ / ´vim´?"** Or is it just so it fits the site?

Comment: PS: I didn't downvote. This "text book problem" is OK. It is just hanging in empty space a bit. Well, replace 'tcl' witch 'perl', and I would like to see a couple of solutions. Even in C. I'll put you back to 0!

Answer (score 0):

This

```
G
/^(.).*\n\1/    { P; d }
s/^(.)(.*)\n.*/\1\n\1\2/
p
s/^(.)\n.*/\1/
h
```

is a sed program that could serve as inspiration. It does this:

```
]# cat infile 
alpha
and
alas
arc
fat
foo
zoo
boat
bee
bed

]# ./letter-group.sed infile 
a
alpha
and
alas
arc
f
fat
foo
z
zoo
b
boat
bee
bed
```

---

It needs some changes, but the basic idea can be reused I think. `info sed` for details.

---

```
#!/bin/sed -Enf

# Insert a title line (group header) when first letter changes
#
#
# If first letter stays the same, just print input line and exit
#
G
/^(.).*\n\1/    { P; d }


# new letter: move it to first line, and print
#
s/^(.)(.*)\n.*/\1\n\1\2/
p

# hold the new letter
s/^(.)\n.*/\1/
h
```

Here you see all these elements: `s///`, `\1`, and hold/get. If you come up with some interesting specs I might try to adapt, but this exaample is a bit dry.