# exit in script shuts down shell

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian

I am learning shell scripting. My platform is a Debian 10 cloud server. I am testing the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo This script will exit with an exit status of 0.
exit 0
```

When I run this it terminates my session! In other words, my terminal window disappears.

My understanding is that `exit`, run within a shell script, simply terminates the script, not the entire session. Maybe Debian 10 departs from this pattern? If so, how do I return a value from within a shell script on Debian 10?

Comment: How exactly are you executing the script? are you perhaps sourcing rather than running it?

Comment: The script is called 'ex01.sh'. I run it using the period command: . ex01.sh

Answer (score 2):

bash man page:

```
 .      filename [arguments]
 source filename [arguments]

   Read and execute commands from filename in the current shell environment...
```

"Sourcing" is the quite generic term here. It means executing the commands from the script file as if you type them one line after the other. You stay in your same bash, and also have all the variables and settings.

"Running" a script includes defining *how* exactly. Often you call a interpreter. `bash script.sh` is just like `perl script.pl`. The suffixes don't matter. What matters is that first "binfmt" line: `#!...`: `./script` or `script` (if it is in $PATH) is all that is needed.

`. script` (sourcing)

`./script` ("running", needs +x)

is not the same, technically.

---

A shell *is* your "entire" session, in a way. Ctrl-D has a similar effect. It can be controlled, but since a interactive shell is just like a script, it is logical.

Try

```
]# ps  
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
18768 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
18994 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
]# bash
]# bash
]# ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
18780 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
18781 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
18782 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
18994 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
]# exit
exit
]# exit
exit
]# ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
18784 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
18994 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
]#
```

...to see how you can pile a shell upon another, and also exit.

This all has to do with processes and jobs.

Comment: Regarding that paragraph about running a script, it seems to state that running `bash script.sh` would read the hashbang line. It doesn't. `bash script.sh` runs the script with Bash, `perl script.sh` runs the script using Perl. Neither is the same as `./script.sh`, see:  [Does the shebang determine the shell which runs the script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87560/170373). (Except that Perl itself _does_ interpret the hashbang, but that's a quirk _of Perl_, it's not the common case for a usual interpreter.)

Comment: yes it is not 100% clear there. I mentioned 'binfmt', because that is the kernel config symbol to support `#!`. The extension is the "binfmt misc", as I understand. Does not `sed` also look for options in the first line?

Comment: it's in `fs/binfmt_script.c` and the config option is `BINFMT_SCRIPT` in Linux. `binfmt_misc` is different. What first line would `sed` read for options from?

Comment: @ilkkachu Here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/550829/how-to-do-string-replace-variable-value-on-one-of-lines-appearing-between-two I pasted a `sed` script; `#!/bin/sed` is one thing; the `-n` option the other.

Comment: yes, sure, you can put arguments in the hashbang line (or _an_ argument, on Linux). But there it's not `sed` itself that reads the hashbang line, it's the kernel which reads it, and launches `sed` with whatever's in there. But if you run `somecmd script.sh` the kernel doesn't read the hashbang, it's just `somecmd` that gets launched. But in the case of `perl script.sh`, _Perl itself_ reads the hashbang, and launches whatever's in there instead, but that's _only because Perl is funny that way_. (It's a compatibility thing for systems that don't support hashbang, or something.)

Answer (score 1):

@steeldriver is right. If I run the script using any of the following it works as desired:

```
./ex01.sh
sh ex01.sh
bash ex01.sh
```

Reference:

```
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/run-execute-sh-shell-script/
```